# "SqlDateTime overflow" error with DataSets over remoting

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime, remoting, strongly-typed-dataset

We have a web-based Windows forms (DNF2!) / remoting (!) / SQL Server (2008R2!) system that was happily passing typed pretty large and varied DataSets back and forth across the web from various time zones.

We recently improved the system and things looked good until users started getting sporadic "SqlDateTime overflow" errors (stack trace below). Sporadic i.t.o. some tables caused issues occasionally, others not at all.

We eventually figured out this only occurs when the client and web server time zones differ - behind or ahead.

Also it **only occurs if a DateTime field is blank**!

From the stack trace it appears to be a serialization problem. This was confirmed during investigation which shows it hits the BL on the web server (`My.Application.Log.WriteEntry` shows the date field with date or NULL) but doesn't hit the database (SQL Profiler shows nothing).

We did notice during debugging that we were getting an MDA warning:

> *A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times. This can happen when calling DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format specifier, which will include a local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the 'Z' format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the 'o' format string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text. This can also occur when passing a DateTime to be serialized by XmlConvert or DataSet. If using XmlConvert.ToString, pass in XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind to serialize correctly. **If using DataSet, set the DateTimeMode on the DataColumn object to DataSetDateTime.Utc**.*

We dutifully followed BillG's advice (i.e. changing the **`DateTimeMode`** to **`UTC`**) but this made no difference at all :(

We found changing all the DateTime fields to text also resolved the problem though this left us wide open to other rather serious issues!

So while we have some work-arounds they are not viable solutions.

A side note - we were also trying to do compression on the some of the DataSet data (converting the entire DataSet to a byte stream and using the `System.IO.Compression`), but this error was not consistently the found in the compressioned DataSets - and besides we removed the compression completely while clutching at straws!

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Server stack trace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
   at K2.ADAMData.MaterialDataSetTableAdapters.MaterialTableAdapter.Update(MaterialDataTable dataTable)
   at K2.ADAMServerClasses.Material.SaveMaterials(Byte[] EncConStr, MaterialDataTable ChangesTable)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at K2.ADAMServerClasses.Material.SaveMaterials(Byte[] EncConStr, MaterialDataTable ChangesTable)
   at K2.ADAM.MaterialEditForm.SaveData() in C:\Data\Clients\K2\Software\ADAM\Development\2.1 HHI\UI\Forms\MaterialEditForm.vb:line 279
   at K2.ADAM.MaterialEditForm.SaveButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Data\Clients\K2\Software\ADAM\Development\2.1 HHI\UI\Forms\MaterialEditForm.vb:line 551
```

Answer (score 1):

So, while preparing this Question I had an epiphany...

Early on while working on improving performance (the serialisation of DataSets was about 8 times the size of the actual data!) we changed the `DataSet.RemotingFormat=Binary`.

Well, blow me down if this doesn't lose the plot when presented with a different time zone!

I can only assume that Binary serialisation does something weird with NULLs? Maybe it uses "1-Jan-0001" with an "isNull=true" attribute or something?

Anyhoo, change the `DataSet.RemotingFormat=XML` and the users are once again happy - and even the stream compression works dandy.

Note to self - do NOT use binary remoting format with SQL dates.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your findings